# My gregorian calendar doesn't display correctly

Tags: java

My Gregorian calendar is displaying like a stair case and keeps repeating from 1 on each line. What I am doing wrong?

```
 package unit8_1gregoriancalendar;
 import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial") // This will suppress problems with the class
 public class Lab8_1GregorianCalendar extends GregorianCalendar 
 {
 // Create a Gregorian calendar type        
 static GregorianCalendar gregorianObject = new GregorianCalendar();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
// This gets the current month, but need to add one for January = 0 in the            GregorianCalendar
int currentMonth = gregorianObject.get(Lab8_1GregorianCalendar.MONTH)+1;
int currentYear = gregorianObject.get(Lab8_1GregorianCalendar.YEAR);

printOutMonth(currentYear, currentMonth);
} // This ends Main() Method

static void printOutMonth(int year, int month) 
{
    int startDay = gregorianObject.get(Lab8_1GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int monthDaysEnd = howManyDays(month,year);

    //This Displays the Calendar Header
    String monthName = getMonthName();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("          " + monthName + " " + year);
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    System.out.println(" Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");

    fillTheCells(startDay, monthDaysEnd);

} // This ends printOutMonth Method

static int howManyDays(int month, int year)
{
    switch(month)
    {
        case 1: return 31;
        case 2:{ if (gregorianObject.isLeapYear(year))
                    return 29;
                 else
                    return 28;
               }
        case 3: return 31;
        case 4: return 30;
        case 5: return 31;
        case 6: return 30;
        case 7: return 31;
        case 8: return 31;
        case 9: return 30;
        case 10: return 31;
        case 11: return 30;
        case 12: return 31;
        default: return 30;
    } // month switch case
}  // this ends howManyDays method
static String getMonthName()
{
    int monthIndicator = gregorianObject.get(Lab8_1GregorianCalendar.MONTH);
        switch (monthIndicator)
        {
            case 0: return "January";
            case 1:return "February";
            case 2: return "March";
            case 3: return "April";
            case 4: return "May";
            case 5: return "June";
            case 6: return "July";
            case 7: return "August";
            case 8: return "September";
            case 9: return "October";
            case 10: return "November";
            case 11: return "December";
            default: return "Month";
        } // This ends monthIndicator Switch Structure
}   // This ends getMonthName

static void fillTheCells(int intStartDay, int innerMonthDaysEnd)
{   //The dayCellCount loop = 7 days per week
    // Tells it to print what fits on that week AND only til end of month
    int dayCellCount=1;
    for(int weekCellCount=1; weekCellCount <= 6; weekCellCount++)
    {
        if(weekCellCount==1);
            dayCellCount=1;

        while((dayCellCount<=weekCellCount*7)&&((dayCellCount-intStartDay)<=innerMonthDaysEnd))
        {
            //Print 4 blanks per day until you get to where the month begins
            if(dayCellCount<=intStartDay)
            {
                System.out.print("    ");
            } 
            // This will Print 3 blanks and the date if date has just 1 digit
            else if(dayCellCount-intStartDay<10)
            {
                System.out.print("   "+(dayCellCount-intStartDay));
            }
            // This will Print 2 blanks and the date if the date has 2 digits until the end of month
            else if(dayCellCount-intStartDay <= innerMonthDaysEnd)
            {
                System.out.print("  " +(dayCellCount-intStartDay));
            }
            // This will get the dayCellCount to step from day to day
            dayCellCount++; 
        } // This ends the dayCellCount

        System.out.println();
    } // This ends the weekCellCount loop
    intStartDay=(intStartDay+innerMonthDaysEnd)%7;       
} // This ends fillTheCells() Method
} // This ends the Lab8_1GregorianCalendar Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Post the error/exception stack if you getting any.

Comment: If you a not required to use the old (and poorly designed) date API, please have a look at [the new one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html), or if you're at Java 7 or lower, the [Joda time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). These APIs have a good toolset for date arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(weekCellCount==1); <-----
```

You have a semicolon at the end of your if statement, so it is being treated as a blank statement, and the following line which sets the dayCellCount is run for every week.